# Crystal Reports, RightToLeft Property

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

In my program I am using Crystal Reports 13 in my soft, and I need them to make readable for Arabic UI too. Everything from right to left. Wanna know, if there is a RightToLeft property for that Reports and I can't make that report templates twice, because there are lot of them. What can you offer to do. I have searched through Google, and only found one solution

One of the solutions for this (without creating extra copy of the same report) is to modify existing report(s) to have 2 sections for each row (if it's feasible) i.e. one for Left to Right Orientation and the other for Right to Left Orientation and display them conditionally based on Langauge selected.

But it will be a lot, really lot work and I think there will be another way to solve this problem. 
Thanks

Comment: no answer programmers ? :/

Comment: hey no one knows the solution ? :(